# find patterns in a string using python regex

Tags: python, regex

Seems to be an easy question, but I miss something in regex groups I guess.
I have a string and I need to find how many occurrences of three patterns it has.

```
string="AGTGCTGGCCGATATGCNYGGAATATATGCAGTGGTGNTT"

pattern1="GGCCTATATGC"
pattern2="GGAANATATGC"
pattern3="GGCCGATATGC"
```

The idea is to use regular expressions.

I tried:

```
re.findall(r"GG[C,A]{2}[A-Z](AT){2}GC", string)
```

However, I do something wrong in `(AT){2}`, because with just writing `ATAT` it works. Is it somehow related to groups in regex? Would appreciate if someone can explain.

Thanks,

Comment: `[C,A]{2}` is wrong. Not only does it match commas, but also `AC` or `CA`. If you want to match `AA` or `CC`, the easiest way to do that is `(?:AA|CC)`.

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey! And thanks for pointing to the duplicate!